# Closed sets with filters

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, filters

I am studying topological vector spaces, and, being at the begin of the textbook (Sevres) I frequently encounter rephrasing and generalisations of known results about metric spaces in terms of filters.
In particular, it is known that in a metric space

A is a closed set in a metric space M IFF any sequence contained in A, which converges to a point x, converges in A (i.e. x belongs to A)

I was trying to prove something as:

"A is a closed set in a TVS E IFF any filter on A converging to a point x, converges in A (i.e. x belongs to A)"

Left to right  implication sounds ok, but I can't prove the opposite, without adding the hypothesis of Hausdorff space on E 
(indeed satisfied by metrizable spaces)

Is this condition necessary? Is there any more general criterion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This holds true in any topological space:

> $A$ is closed in $X$ iff for every filterbase $\mathcal{F}$ on $A$ (i.e. consisting of subsets of $A$) that converges to $x$ in $X$ we have that $x \in A$.

Proof sketch: suppose $A$ is closed and we have such a filterbase $\mathcal{F}$ on $A$, then for every neighbourhood $O$ of $x$ we have that $O$ contains some $F \in \mathcal{F}$ and thus $O \cap A \neq \emptyset$; this implies $x \in \overline{A}=A$. For the reverse, suppose $A$ satisfies the filterbase property and let $x \in \overline{A}$, then $\{O \cap A: O \text{ (open) neighbourhood of } x\}$ is a filterbase on $A$ that converges to $x$, so by the property $x \in A$ and so $A$ is closed.

No metric or Hausdorffness is needed, which is why filters are popular.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is precisely what I was trying to do, and the first part of my proof is identical to yours. Also my try to prove the reverse starts  identical.Where I imposed housdorffness was to prove the filter you defined converges to x and not to a generic element y belonging to A, how can I get that point?

Comment: @FrancescoBilotta apply the definition of convergence to $x$. I don’t care if it also converges to another point. That’s irrelevant.

Comment: Yes perfectly right, I just realized it as I sent my comment! So used to reason with sequences and uniqueness of limits!

Comment: @FrancescoBilotta Very often unicity of limits of sequences is unnecessary too, in general spaces.